# Force thread not to give back CPU until a part is finished

Tags: c#, multithreading

Consider two threads run simultaneously. A is reading and B is writing. When A is reading, in the middle of code ,CPU time for A finishes then B thread continues.

Is there any way to don't give back CPU until A finishes, but B can start or continue?

Comment: Is thread A reading the data that thread B is writing? Is this an example of the [Producer/Consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)? Or are you wanting to simply block one thread until another thread is finished or otherwise signals?

Comment: Yes. I don't want in the middle of A give the CPU back . But maybe B thread has something to write . You know, if in the middle of A CPU time finishes, data that has been retrieved is not complete.

Comment: You still haven't made it clear if A and B are sharing resources or not. Please post some code that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: A fills a ConcurrentQueue and B read the queue .but queue data are complete . A can read a data incompletely that causes error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that you have **almost no control** over when CPU is given back and to whom it is given. The operating system does that. To have control on that, you'd need to be the operating system. The only things you can usually do are:

- start a thread
- set thread priority, so some threads are **may more likely** get time than others
- put a thread to sleep, **immediatelly** and ask the operating system to wake it up upon some condition, maybe with some timeout (waiting time limit)

as a special case, or a typical use case, the second point is often also provided with a shorthand:

- put a thread to sleep, **immediatelly** for a specified amount of time

By "sleep" I mean that this thread is paused and will not get any CPU time, even if all CPUs are idle, unless the thread is woken up by the OS due to some condition.

Furthermore, in a typical case, there is no "thread A and thread B that switch CPU time between them", but there is "lots of threads from various processes and the operating system itself, and you two threads". This means that when your thread A loses the CPU, most probably it will not be the thread B that gets the time now. Some other thread from somewhere else will get it, and at some future point of time, maybe your thread A or maybe thread B will get it back.

This means that there is very little you can be sure. You can be sure that your threads are

- either dead
- or sleeping
- or proceeding 'forward' in a hard to determine order

If you need to ensure that some threads are **synchronized**, you must .. not start them simultaneously, or put them sleep in precise moments and wake them up in precise order.

---

You've just said in comments:

> You know, if in the middle of A CPU time finishes, data that has been retrieved is not complete

This means that you need to ensure that thread B does not try to touch the data before thread A finishes writing it. But also, if you think about it, you need to ensure that thread A doesn't start writing next data if the thread B is now reading previous data.

This means synchronization. This means that threads A and B must **wait** if the other thread is touching the data. This means that they need to be put to sleep and woken up when the other thread finishes.

In C#, the easiest way to do that is to use `lock(x)` keyword. When a thread enters a `lock()` section, it proceeds only if it is able to get the lock. If not, it is put to sleep. It can't get the lock if any other thread was faster and got it before. However, a thread releases the lock when it ends its job. Upon that time, one of the sleeping threads is woken up and given the lock.

```
lock(fooo) {  // <- this line means 'acquire the lock or sleep'

    iam.doing(myjob);
    very.important(things);
    thatshouldnt.be.interrupted();
    byother(threads);

} // <- this line means 'release the lock'
```

So, when a thread gets through the `lock(fooo){` line, you can't be sure it won't be interrupted. Oh, surely it will be. OS will switch the threads back and forth to other processes, and so on. But you can be sure that **no other threads of your app** will be inside the code block. If they tried to get inside while your thread got that lock, they'd imediatelly fall asleep in the first `lock` line. One of them be will be later woken up when your thread gets out of that code.

There's one more thing. `lock()` keyword requires a parameter. I wrote `foo` there. You need to pass there something that will **act as the lock**. It can be any object, even plain object:

```
private object thelock = new object();

private void dosomething()
{
    lock(thelock)
    {
        foobarize(thebaz);
    }
}
```

however you **must ensure that all threads** try to use the same lock instance. Writing a code like

```
private void dosomething()
{
    object thelock = new object();
    lock(thelock)
    {
        foobarize(thebaz);
    }
}
```

is a nonsense since every potential thread executing that lines will try lockin upon their own new object instance and will see it as "free" (it's new, just created, noone took it earlier) and will immediatelly get into the protected code block.

---

Now you wrote about using `ConcurrentQueue`. This class provides safely mechanisms against concurrency. You can be sure that adding or reading or removing items from that queue is already safe. This collection makes it safe. You don't need to add synchronization to add or remove items safely. It's safe. If you observe any ill effects, then most probably you have tried putting an item into that collection and then you were **modifying that item**. Concurrent collection will not guard you against that. It can only make sure that add/remove/etc are safe. But it has no knowledge or control on what you do to the items:

In short, if some thread B tries to read items from the collection, then **in thread A** this is NOT safe:

```
concurrentcoll.Add(item);
item.x = 5;
item.foobarize();
```

but this is safe:

```
item.x = 5;
item.foobarize();
concurrentcoll.Add(item);
// and do not touch the Item anymore here.
```